# Jenkins/Cloudbees embeddable wall view for all projects

Tags: java, continuous-integration, jenkins, hudson, cloudbees

I need a static wall view for Jenkins (more precise Cloudbess) project that:

1. Generate static html/image
2. Expand folders and show info for each build including projects in folders
3. For each build I need last build info: build id, status and build time
4. In ideal case will use as a standalone web page that must refresh Cloudbees/Jenkins stat (i.e. contains authentication to Cloudbess account etc).

Any thoughts will be appreciated (please, don't ask me to write all that by hands or provide relatively simple API guide)

Answer (score 1):

all data you request are available via jenkins REST API. See http://your.jenkins/api for details, and https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API for some tips on using this API with the adequate depth and filtering.